# Bubble sort descending

Tags: sorting, bubble-sort

So I want to write a bubble sort code that sorts random numbers in descending order. This is the code I wrote:

```
void BubbleSort(int data[], int size)
{
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <=size-1; j++)
        {
            if (data[j] <data[j + 1])
            {
                swap(data[j], data[j+1]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Where swap is this:

```
void Swap(int &x, int &y)
{
   int temp = x;
   x = y;
   y = temp;
}
```

When I run the code it won't sort anything, it just keeps the random numbers in the same order as when they were generated. I am not sure what's wrong with my code, I tried to trace it on paper and it worked well; could it be something with the sort function?

Edit: I just fixed the outer and inner loop, yet it's still not sorting.

Thanks!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Your outer loop is wrong. You need to use a while loop with a flag, as bubble sort needs to continue until no swaps occur.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = size - 1; i < 0; i--)
```

i < 0 is never true because you start with i > 0

change it to:

```
for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```